# Unexpected Identifier in Javascript for speech

Tags: javascript

I'm making a Visual Novel and I've come across an error in the code for the speech from the main character. 
Here is the code which I've tried using.

```
chapter1 = {
    label, "chapter1"
    text, {
        value: "Ughhhh",
        speaker: "Me",
        append: false,
        align: "left"
    },
];
```

Can I ask what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing?
And also, I've checked it out and it says that the unexpected identifier is the `text, {` part of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the format you're looking for:

```
chapter1 = {
    label: "chapter1",
    text: {
        value: "Ughhhh",
        speaker: "Me",
        append: false,
        align: "left"
    }
};
```

Your last bracket didn't match up, and you had commas instead of colons to set values.